# Inserting special characters (č,š and ž) into mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

I was experimenting with how special characters such as č, š and ž appear in the database, once inserted. Inserting the string "č_š_ž" looks like this in the database (varchar field): "Ä_Å¡_Å¾". For me it is not a problem how the string appears in the database, but as it seems it still looks like "Ä_Å¡_Å¾" when I fetch it back from the database and render it in HTML with this meta (if it matters):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

I also tried real-escaping the string before inserting it, but the result stays the same. Anyone knows a good way to deal with that? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your table's encoding to `utf8_general_ci`, this makes MySQL physically store and retrieve values encoded in `UTF-8` .

And read this : [**Database Character Set and Collation**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-database.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$set_utf=$dbh->exec("SET NAMES UTF8");
```

Answer (score -1):

make sure your characters are related to the language you are using. When i used hindi characters i used this in my :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="hi" />
```

And also after connecting to your database add in this line of code:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");
```